# How to move a wheel arch liner without snapping/breaking it?

Tags: bumper

Hyundai coupe 2.0 2006.

I'm trying to remove a front bumper/access a nut which goes from the edge of the front bumper to the bottom of the wing/fender.

I can see you need to move part of the wheel arch linerout of the wing however if I push with my hand seems I could tear or bend it.  Actually I damaged the liner before by doing this.

Is there a way to handle arch liners in order to move it out of the wing so you can put your hand inbetween the two.  Does the whole arch need to be removed.

Comment: make sure it is warm - plastic can break when cold.

Comment: Really the answer is "very carefully".  These things can be tough to remove even when new and they seem to stiffen up as they age.  You might try warming it with a heater a bit before trying to take it out.  I recommend you remove it to access things behind it rather than trying to bend it out of the way.

Comment: @jwh20 In this case might it be simpler to remove the top of the wing then push your hand in and access the bottom bolt, or is that likely to do damage as well?